# UTF-8 Não funciona em todas as páginas

Tags: php, html, mvc, utf-8

Estou com problemas ao utilizar o `charset='UTF-8'`. Estou desenvolvendo um site para um projeto da faculdade utilizando MVC e como de padrão declarei o `utf-8` em uma view pra ser utilizada como padrão para as outras views, porém na maioria das páginas o unicode funciona, e em outras não, sendo que uso o mesmo padrão para todas as views. Alguém sabe alguma forma de corrigir isso ou o por que desse erro?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <base href="/<?php echo $baseUrl ?>" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>
            <?=$title?>
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section>
            <?php $this->controller->renderView();?> 
        </section>
        
    </body>
```

Comment: Qual o problema que apresenta?

Comment: Em algumas views é como se eu não estivesse declarado o utf-8

Comment: poste seu código das views que não funcionam por favor e veja antes, se realmente declarou a tag <meta charset='UTF-8' .... >

Comment: @ÐvÐ Boa tarde, eu não utilizo includes

Comment: @Victor postei o código base que eu uso no site

Comment: Veja se resolve colocando isso no arquivo web.config: `<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="pt-br" />`

Answer (score 0):

Eu não tenho certeza se isso vai funcionar mas eu acredito que sim, então tenta issso:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`